# What key combination changes letter case in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

In my code I have several places where a SQL-like query is built and there all keywords must be uppercase.

Something like `SELECT L1 FROM SOMETHING`.

But somehow it is changed to `Select L1 FROM SOMETHING`.

Is there some key combination that causes this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165341.aspx), the keyboard shortcuts are:

- *UPPERCARSE*: **Ctrl-Shift-U**
- *lowercase*:  **Ctrl-U**

Comment: That I know and isn't the problem. It is that some code is changed while I didn't touch it.